# C programming beginner - Please explain this error

Tags: c, arrays

I'm just starting off with C and was trying out a few examples from Ritchie's book. I wrote a small program to understand character arrays, but stumbled on some errors, and was hoping for some insight on what I've understood wrong:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ARRAYSIZE 50
#include <string.h>

main () {
  int c,i;
  char letter[ARRAYSIZE];
  i=0;
  while ((c=getchar()) != EOF )
  {    
    letter[i]=c;
    i++;
  }
  letter[i]='\0';
  printf("You entered %d characters\n",i);
  printf("The word is ");

  printf("%s\n",letter);
  printf("The length of string is %d",strlen(letter));
  printf("Splitting the string into chars..\n");
  int j=0;
  for (j=0;j++;(j<=strlen(letter)))
    printf("The letter is %d\n",letter[j]);
}
```

The output is:

```
$ ./a.out 
hello how are youYou entered 17 characters
The word is hello how are you
The length of string is 17Splitting the string into chars..
```

What is happening? Why isn't the for loop giving any output?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The syntax should be;

```
for (j=0; j<strlen(letter); j++)
```

Since `strlen` is costy operation, and you don't modify the string inside the loop, it's better to write like:

```
const int len = strlen(letter);
for (j=0; j<=len; j++)
```

Besides, it's strongly recommanded to always check for buffer overflow when working with C-strings and user-input:

```
while ((c=getchar()) != EOF && i < ARRAYSIZE - 1)
```

Comment: Thanks for that tip too. I'll add error checks soon. Thought I'd clear the basics. See how I got wrong even in the syntax of for! :)

Answer (score 7):

The error is in the for, simply swap the ending condition and the increment like this:

```
for (j = 0; j <= strlen(letter); j++)
```

**Question:**  what's that last character?

Comment: `j<strlen(letter)` & not `j<=strlen(letter)`?

Comment: @another.anon.coward: of course, but I think that seeing the null terminator is benefical to the op

Comment: Thank you. Fumbled on basic syntax!

Comment: @Droidzone: I got stuck in this same problem too when I began! :D

Answer (score 4):

`for (j=0;j++;(j<=strlen(letter)))` it's not correct.

It should be `for (j=0; j<=strlen(letter); j++)` - increment at the third position.

Answer (score 3):

The correct format of `for` loop is:

```
for (initialization_expression; loop_condition; increment_expression){
    // statements
}
```

so your `for` loop should be

```
for (j = 0; j < strlen(letter); j++)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the for loop, the condition is i++, which evaluates to false (0) the first time. You need to swap them: `for (j=0; j <= strlen(letter); j++)`

Comment: +1: Only answer here so far which try to explains why the loops does not print any output